# Cannot access global array in other JavaScript function

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

When the `txtPhones` array cannot store value it gives a blank alert.
`alert(txtPhones);` gives nothing in `removefromlist()` function.
When I check `txtPhones` in `createSpanforuser()` function it gives the perfect value,
but  `txtPhones` is blank in `removefromlist`:

```
var txtPhones=[];
function createSpanforuser(id, uname) {
  
    txtPhones=uname.split(",");
    document.getElementById("tdTeliphone").innerHTML="";
    alert(txtPhones); //gives correct value
    for(var lp=0;lp<txtPhones.length;lp++){
       var myID=lp+"span4"+id; 
       document.getElementById("tdTeliphone").innerHTML+="<span id="+myID+"> " +txtPhones[lp]+"<span id=Inner"+myID+" class=hyper onclick='removefromlist(\"" + myID + "\",\"" + txtPhones[lp] + "\")'> <img class=imgspan  src=../img/cross-script.png style=width:14px;height:14px /> </span> </span> </br>";
    
    }

}

function removefromlist(idSpan, uname) {
        $('#' + idSpan).remove();
        alert(txtPhones); //gives blank
}
```

Comment: What exactly is the problem?

Comment: Why are there two functions of `createSpanforuser`? function createSpanforuser(id, uname) { <-- var txtPhones=[]; function createSpanforuser(id, uname) { <-- wtf? I'm sure if you get rid of the first function `txtPhones` will be a global array and it should be accessible in both functions. Let us know if that is the fix.

Comment: it is mistake
it is actually like this
    var txtPhones=[];
    function createSpanforuser(id, uname) {

Comment: alert(txtPhones); gives blank value in removefromlist()

Comment: do u have any idea @ Aadit M Shah

Comment: Not really sure. Is it possible you are calling `removefromlist` before you call `createSpanforuser`?

Comment: no @aug it is not possiable

Comment: ok well I tried doing it in my console and your `txtPhones` variable should be a global. I also tried calling `createSpanforuser` and passed in "hi,hi,hi,hi" and I got the appropriate alert. I then called removefromlist and I still got the alert. Is there possibly something else we are missing here?